# Avoid error 403 quotaExceeded for making multiple axios HTTP requests on google API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, axios, google-api-nodejs-client

I need to make a big loop of requests on Google API by using axios, in my back-end NodeJS.

But Google API blocks at a certain time with error 403 when you flood him of requests. As it is said in the documentation we need to use the exponential back-off method https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits

> Retry using exponential back-off. You need to slow down the rate at
>   which you are sending the requests.
>
> The flow for implementing simple exponential backoff is as follows.
>
> ```
> Make a request to the API
> Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
> Wait 1s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
> Retry request
> Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
> Wait 2s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
> Retry request
> Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
> Wait 4s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
> Retry request
> Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
> Wait 8s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
> Retry request
> Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
> Wait 16s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
> Retry request
> If you still get an error, stop and log the error.
> ```

My code below

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const axios = require("axios");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const scopeGooleAPI = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
];

var clientGoogleAPI = new google.auth.JWT(
  client_email,
  null,
  private_key,
  scopeGooleAPI,
  "admin@admin.com"
);

router.post("/insertResourceHTTP", (req, res) => {
  if (!clientGoogleAPI)
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json("Google G Suite Credentials have not been found in the .env file");

  return clientGoogleAPI.authorize((err, tokens) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);

    let config = {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + tokens.access_token }
    };

    let axiosArray = [];

    function callHttpRequestGoogle(i, s = 1) {
      return axios
        .post(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/resources/calendars",
          {
            //json : true,
            resourceId: "resourceIdPromise" + i, // required
            resourceName: "resourceNamePromise" + i, // required
            // buildingId: "",
            // capacity: 0,
            // etags: "",
            // floorName: "",
            // floorSection: "",
            generatedResourceName: "generatedResourceNamePromise" + i,
            kind: "admin#directory#resources#calendars#CalendarResource",
            resourceCategory: "OTHER",
            resourceDescription: "resourceDescription",
            resourceEmail: "resourceEmail",
            resourceType: "resourceType",
            userVisibleDescription: "userVisibleDescription"
          },
          config
        )
        .then(responseCatched => {
          return { responseCatched: responseCatched };
        })
        .catch(errorCatched => {
          if (errorCatched.response.data.error.code === 403) {
            console.log(errorCatched.response.data.error.code, s, i);
            s += 1;
            return axiosArray.push(
              setTimeout(() => {
                callHttpRequestGoogle(i, s);
              }, s * 1000)
            );
          }
          return { errorCatched: errorCatched };
        });
    }

    for (let i = 12300; i < 12800; i++) {
      axiosArray.push(callHttpRequestGoogle(i));
    }

    Promise.all(axiosArray).then(OKK => {
      console.log("Array completed");
      axios
        .all(axiosArray)
        .then(
          axios.spread((...argsResponse) => {
            let responseArray = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < argsResponse.length; i++) {
              // 3 cases : There is an error, there is no error, or there is an unknown error
              if (argsResponse[i].hasOwnProperty("errorCatched")) {
                responseArray.push({
                  return: argsResponse[i].errorCatched.response.data.error,
                  data: JSON.parse(
                    argsResponse[i].errorCatched.response.config.data
                  )
                });
              } else if (argsResponse[i].hasOwnProperty("responseCatched")) {
                responseArray.push({
                  return: "Item well added statusCode 200",
                  data: argsResponse[i].responseCatched.data
                });
              } else {
                responseArray.push({
                  return: "unknown error, sorry about that"
                });
              }
            }
            res.status(200).json(responseArray);
          })
        )
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).json(err.message);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

The promise doesn't wait completely for the end of the array `let axiosArray = [];` to be completed. The promise only cares of the first loop

```
for (let i = 12300; i < 12800; i++) {
  axiosArray.push(callHttpRequestGoogle(i));
}
```

Because `axiosArray` is fed in a second time by pushing again when there was  a rejection detected in the .catch `.catch(errorCatched => {})`

The problem is that this line `console.log("Array completed");` is executed and by consequences also `res.status(200).json(responseArray);` which quits the script.

I can see it is still working in background because `console.log(errorCatched.response.data.error.code, s, i);` are returned and it goes even sometimes to 10 seconds of incrementation.

```
axiosArray.push(
  setTimeout(() => {
    callHttpRequestGoogle(i, s);
  }, s * 1000)
);
```

You won't be able to run this script if you don't have a Google G suite account. And also your own credentials on a classical Google developer account.

But do you have any suggestions to tell me, an alternative ?

Comment: `Promise.all` is fail-fast. You need to redesign your code logic to ensure that instead you get results for every request, or tried enough times with exponential backoff that you should flag that request for later use when quota/connectivity is restored.

Comment: Thank you for your return, at first I was using axios.all and axios.spread and this the good version I wanted to share, not the one with Promise.all

Comment: This code is not valid Google Apps Script - are you sure that tag should be present? GAS is JavaScript 1.6 that runs in Google's servers.

Comment: For me yes it is a valid Google Apps Script because I am using the NodeJS module const { google } = require("googleapis"); and also because I am using the JWT Google Json Web Token authentification via NodeJS again.

Comment: Those are not Google Apps Script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Hello I found the solution myself, you just have to add await here axiosArray.push(await callHttpRequestGoogle(i)) and to add async here return clientGoogleAPI.authorize(async (err, tokens) => {}); Cheers !!!